# I need to update age in SQL Server 2008 according to DOB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008, which has DOB (e.g. 1992-03-15) and in same table, I have an `Age` column, which is right now Null. I need to update the `Age` according to the DOB. I have both columns (AGE and DOB) in the same table. I need script which does my job to update `Age` according to DOB

And other one is in same table, I have Arrival Month (e.g. 8) and Arrival year (e.g. 2011), according to that I need to update another column (Time in country). Say let's say according to example (08(MM), 2011(YYYY)), should update (TimeInCountry) - 4.2 something like that. Which should deduct from current date and time has mentioned into month and year

Do let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I have tried to find out the age using various function but didn't find anything where I can update the rest of values in age. I meant existing tables.

Comment: Just my opinion, but did you (or the person designing this db) consider that you will constantly need to update AGE for every record? Maybe look into [Computed Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Concerning the computation, look into [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: No, this is one time script, I have to update ages for all the person.

Comment: This is porr design and contrary to Normalisation. One should NOT make such an update. The age is a calculated field. Point.

Comment: Also using .2 as 2 months is really bad idea, since .10 is not the same as .1 and .11 is supposed to be bigger than .9... Use proper date formats instead

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the data type your age column is

You can do something like below

```
Update TableName
Set Age = DATEDIFF(yy, DOB, getdate())
```

if you using decimal

```
Age = DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,GETDATE())/8766.0
```

I believe creating a trigger bill be use full, if you adding new rows in future

Comment: I have ran your query - Age = DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,GETDATE())/8766.0

Comment: @HarshalChoksi: Is everything fine?

Comment: Yes pretty nice for 1st issue i.e. Age but didn't find out the way we should update TimeInCountry based on the ArrivalYear and ArrivalMonth, could you help me. I have arrival month  2 and ArrivalYear 1999, so manual calculation should be 16.8 so I need to update TimeInCountry based  on Month and Year only.

Comment: @HarshalChoksi: How you calcualate 16.8 based on month 2 and year 1999?

Comment: The division with 8766 is not accurate, it just assumes every year has 365.25 days and uses that for calculating ages

Comment: @JamesZ: Feel free to answer with the correct way of doing.

Comment: I would do it using integer calculation in YYYYMMDD format and divide the result with 10000

Comment: @JamesZ: How you determine the date, you have year and month only?

Answer (score 0):

For yopur first Problem,

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET AGE=DATEDIFF(hour,DOB_COLUMN,GETDATE())/8766.0
```

If you want in Round ,

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET 
AGE= CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,DOB_COLUMN,GETDATE())/8766.0,0))
```

And Not Sure what you really want to do in the Second Problem,but my guess you can try something like..

```
Update Table_Name set 
TimeInCountry=cast(len(Arrival_year) as varchar(4))+'.'+cast(len(Arrival_Month) as varchar(2))
```

Comment: Hi Ajmot, Your 2nd query is work perfectly fine and about third point - I give you little clarification. I have ArrivalMonth and ArrivalYear (It is Int) and similar fashion, I have to calculate, TimeInCountry - Here we don't have Day but only have ArrivalMonth and ArrivalYear, So I need to Update TimeInCountry column. I hope you understand this time.

Comment: I ran your query but return me TimeInCountry 4.1 for ArrivalMonth = 2 and ArrivalYear = 1999, instead of that should return me  16.8. Isn't it?

Comment: 16.8?? what's the logic?? please

Comment: Current year - Arrival Year and Same for Current month - Arrival Month. This is a month 10 and year 2015. If we have ArrivalMonth = 2 and Arrival Year = 1999 - How long I have been in specific country?

Comment: The division with 8766 is not accurate, it just assumes every year has 365.25 days and uses that for calculating ages

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented User Defined function
Here it is which may help to someone.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TimeInCountry]
(
 @ArrivalMonth varchar(10),
 @ArrivalYear Varchar(10)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
Declare @Ageyear int
Declare @Agemonth int
Declare @Final varchar(10)
Declare @CurrentMonth int
Declare @Currentyear int
Set @CurrentMonth = (Select DatePart(mm, GetDate()))
Set @Currentyear = (Select DatePart(yyyy,GetDate())) 


Select @AgeYear = @Currentyear - @ArrivalYear
Select @AgeMonth = @CurrentMonth - @ArrivalMonth

if (@AgeMonth < 0) 
BEGIN
                Set @AgeYear = @AgeYear - 1
                Set @AgeMonth = @AgeMonth + 12
END  
Select @Final = (Select Cast(@AgeYear as Varchar(max)) +'.'+ Cast(@AgeMonth as varchar(max)))

Return @Final

---And finally call this function where to update. 

--To Check
 Select [DBName].TimeInCountry (8,2013) 
--- and Finally updating.

Update [DBName].[dbo].[TableName] Set TimeInCountry  = dbo.TimeInCountry (ArrivalMonth,ArrivalYear) from [DBName].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Thanks again everyone.